# How do I change GRANTS for a user in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

```
> show grants for user_readonly;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user_readonly@%                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user_readonly'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F60F5EBDA2568D53C7CBFD0297F1BAA324B06AABD' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'user_readonly'@'%'                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Currently, user_readonly has grants for everything. How can I change this so he can ONLY read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html) does the opposite from grant.  The easiest way is to `REVOKE ALL` and then selectively re-grant the rights the user actually needs.  And generally speaking, `GRANT ALL` should be used cautiously.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it I believe, so the user user_readonly, will only be able to read (i.e. select only).

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO user_readonly @'host' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F60F5EBDA2568D53C7CBFD0297F1BAA324B06AABD';
```

then

```sql
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You may need to change the word  `'host'`  to something which is more appropriate to you.

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0006100000)